# Sticky bit and users with sudo permission

Tags: files, permissions, directory, root, chmod

Let's say I `chmod 1777` a folder `/opt/test` and all files inside it as user **user1**.  Hence **user2** is able to update and edit files inside the `/opt/test` directory.

When **user2** operates via `sudo`, he's able to delete any file from the directory, even those he does not own; is this normal?  If yes, what is the purpose of setting the sticky bit?

When another user **user3** operating without `sudo` tries to delete a file he does not own, he gets a "permission denied" error.

Note: All users belong to the default group.

Comment: The sticky bit can't prevent root from doing what root wants.

Comment: I have edited the original post as it was very unclear, please modify it if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: @dr01, you got it correctly, thanks for rephrasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sticky bit is set, only the *file's owner*, the *directory's owner*, or **root** can rename or delete the file.

The `sudo` command is there to enable a user to *impersonate* another user, including **root**.

When *user2* issues a command through `sudo` to become **root**, he's getting **root's** permissions, and **root** always has all permissions on the system.

Comment: jcbermu, it is not need to become root! If you use sudo to execute command as user1 you will have the required permissions